# Am I writing these contextual selectors, grouping, and anchor selectors correctly in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

This is what I am trying to do:

1. **Create a contextual selector containing the nav, ul and li selectors and add the following**

   a. display inline

   b. margin top and bottom of 0 left and right of 40px
2. **Create a contextual selector containing the nav, ul, li and anchor selectors, grouped with the nav, ul, li, and span selectors and add the following**

   a. text decoration none

   b. color #000
3. **Create a contextual selector containing the nav, ul, li and anchor selectors (the anchor selector will have a hover pseudo class), grouped with the nav, ul, li, and span selectors and add the following**

   a. text decoration underline

This is what I wrote so far:

```
nav ul li {display: inline; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 40px; margin-right: 40px; }
nav, ul, li, span, {text-decoration: none; color: #000; } 
nav, ul, li, a: hover {text-decoration: underline; }
```

Comment: nevermind i got it thanks!

Comment: Did you got the answer?

Comment: For what it's worth, your `margin-*` declarations can be condensed into `margin: 0 40px`. `a: hover` needs that space removed, too.

Comment: You should post your solve as an answer!

Comment: Homework is calling!

Answer (score 0):

Normally I tend to eschew answering exercise questions directly in favor of providing hints, but since you've already figured this one out yourself, I'm posting the full answer for the sake of posterity.

Your answer to #1 is correct. As James Donnelly points out, your four margin declarations can be condensed to `margin: 0px 40px`, but it's not *wrong* to have all four longhands, just verbose.

Your selectors in #2 and #3 are incorrect. Remember that a contextual selector consists of descendant combinators connecting each selector. Following your answer to #1, the two contextual selectors in #2 should be

```
nav ul li a, nav ul li span
```

and the two contextual selectors in #3 should be

```
nav ul li a:hover, nav ul li span
```

Notice the use of only one comma per pair. The comma at the end of your selector in #2 also doesn't belong — in other words, do not add a comma between the end of your selector and the `{` of the declaration block.

Notice also that the space between `:` and `hover` is removed — that space should not be there. The pseudo-class name needs to be connected to the `:`.

Your style declarations are correct.